# SSIS Mysql best practices

Tags: mysql, ssis, etl

We are in the process of moving our backend from ms sql server to mysql. Actually we currently use a couple mysql servers, but mostly ms sql server. I mention this because we are not totally new to mysql. Each day we do a lot of ETL to keep our backend in sync with a legacy system. We move a lot of data and working with sql server has been so much easier than working with mysql for ETL. I know SSIS is MS, but still it has been a headache.

We are using sql server 2012 and BIDS 2010. It has been a struggle to move mysql data at the same rate as ms sql data. We are mainly dealing with innodb tables in mysql. To summarize I have been using the mysql ODBC connector and the ODBC destination in SSIS. The first step is to turn autocommit off on imports. Even with that setting off I can see in package execution that the data source ends up waiting on the destination. It gets about 40,000 rows ahead and waits.

Next I export the data to a text file and then import using a sql task and the INFILE command. This gives pretty good performance, but at the expense of more moving parts. I've had a couple issues with this approach, but it does work and perform well.

Lastly I tried a 3rd party SSIS component from Devart. It creates custom mysql source and destination components. The performance isn't as good as INFILE, but it's not bad and it makes the package simple like when dealing with sql server... a data source and a data destination. No messing with auto commits, exports, INFILE, etc. However I can't use the connections to do other tasks like truncate tables and stuff. So I still have my ODBC connection to do those tasks. I'm going to ask Devart about this.

Right now it looks like Devart is going to be a nice balance. If I absolutely need the performance I have the INFILE method.

I also tried the mysql net connector and could not get that to work at all. I'm running on Windows 7 64bit with Sql Server 2012 64bit. Basically everything I need in BIDS runs in 32bit so I'm guessing this part of issues.

My question is what are others doing when it comes to moving mysql data with SSIS? It has been such a hassle. It would be nice to get some input on what others are doing. What methods are you using? Are you using 3rd party components? Is there a better/dedicated place to discuss SSIS and mysql?

Comment: I just setup linked servers from MSSQL to MySQL and query the MySQL database tables like normal tables inside MSSQL. The performance was acceptable.

Comment: I should have mentioned we are grabbing data from our legacy backend via ODBC. Currently it is being imported into mssql, but in the future it will be to mysql.

Comment: Have you tried Attunity Replicate?